# Sum of two characters

Tags: c, return, ascii

First of all, this is the small program that I've made:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void) {
    char z = '"' + '!';
    printf("%c\n", z);
    return 0;
}
```

The console give me 'C'. So I think this is normal. I've read that when we compute characters they are turning into decimal value.

```
ASCII ----> decimal
'"' ----> 34 
'!"----> 33

34 + 33 = 67
 C-----> 67
```

Everything seems ok.

But, when I try to do : 'a' + 'b', it gives me '\303'. Why?

```
a ---> 97
b ---> 98 

97 + 98 = 195.
```

195 is outside of the ASCII table, so I was expecting to have a error message.

Thank you in advance for your help, and thanks to be comprehensive about my broken English!

Comment: What exactly it prints? It can depend on your encoding set.

Comment: "when we compute characters they are turning into decimal value": Yes, there is no text but encoded text. Knowing which character set and encoding is being used can be extremely important—and it's probably not ASCII. Do `locale` or `chcp` in your console. BTW—'\303' is 195.

Comment: all values of char from -128 to 127 are printable (char in signed value in range [-128, 127]). Following code print all: `int z;for (z = 0; z < 256; z++) printf("%c\n", (char)z);`. `(char)(97 + 98)` equals `-61` due to overflow.

Comment: 303 is 195 in octal.

Comment: "195 is outside of the ASCII table" is true, yet C does not define printing an error message for any run-time code.  The code performed correctly - you only expected an error.  The detail of the problem is in " 'a' + 'b', it gives me '\303'.".  Without posting the code, (instead, you described it), without detail how output was observed  (terminal output, debugger, etc.)  the post is unnecessarily unclear.  In the future recommend to 1) post true code 2) inputs, 3) observed outputs, 4) expected outputs.

Comment: Using math on letters and symbols does not really make sense. In other languages, `'a' + 'b'` yields `"ab"`, but we can only guess what `'a'*'b'` or `'a'/'b'` should return. In other words, what you call "letters" are in fact plain, well defined, *numbers* in C.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Sadly, it won't give an error message.  As is common with C, instead of errors it has "undefined behavior", which makes debugging a lot of problems difficult, because it is syntactically valid but technically wrong.  This is a lot of the reason why exceptions were added in C++, but this is getting off topic.

As mentioned in comments, 'a' + 'b' is in fact 195, which in octal is 303. <s>Reinterpreting the unsigned 195 to a signed value is -61</s> (see below for more on this).  In both cases, they are outside of the printable range for ascii characters.  On my console it prints a � but this is non-standard, different consoles will print different things there.

The fix is to make sure you are passing meaningful data to printf before calling it, and no expecting printf to do the work of detecting it.

Side note: you should turn on all warnings with your compiler, they often catch many of these problems.

Side note 2: if 'a' + 'b' yielded a `signed char`, then it would be -61, but it in fact is a 32 bit int.  You can check this with `sizeof('a' + 'b')` returning 4.  So the number being printed is 195, which still doesn't map to a valid character in the ASCII table.

Comment: There is no undefined behavior here in the `printf()`.  "Reinterpreting the unsigned 195 to a signed value is -61." mis-leads as the sum is not unsigned, but `int`. "different consoles will print different things there" is true, yet that is not undefined behavior, but implementation specified behavior.  `printf("%c\n", 195);` is defined in C as "... the `int` argument is converted to an `unsigned char`, and the resulting character is written."  So "the fix is to make sure you are passing valid data to printf before calling it," is not the _fix_.